# Is it possible to print 'é' as '%C3%A9' in Perl?

Tags: perl, urlencode, html-encode

I have some string with accent like "é" and the goal is to put my string into an URL so I need to convert "é" to "%C3%A9"

I have tested some module as `HTML::Entitie`, `Encode` or `URI::Encode` without any success

**Actual Result:**
`%C3%83%C2%A9`

**Expected Result:**
`%C3%A9`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Entities;
use feature 'say';
use URI::Encode qw( uri_encode );

my $var = "é";
say $var;

$var = uri_encode( $var );

say $var;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `use utf8`.

> The [use utf8](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8) pragma tells the Perl parser to allow UTF-8 in the
> program text in the current lexical scope. The no utf8 pragma tells
> Perl to switch back to treating the source text as literal bytes in
> the current lexical scope. (On EBCDIC platforms, technically it is
> allowing UTF-EBCDIC, and not UTF-8, but this distinction is academic,
> so in this document the term UTF-8 is used to mean both).
>
> **Do not use this pragma for anything else than telling Perl that your script is written in UTF-8.** The utility functions described below are
> directly usable without use utf8;.